# How do I properly handle a string with an apostrophe when using it within a like clause with PDO?

Tags: php, string, pdo, apostrophe

I am attempting to do a string search with a like clause using PDO. The name has an apostrophe. All my attempts thus far have resulted in no results found even though the names exist.

This code works, where I have hardcoded the array values:

```
// looking for last names that start with A' and any first name
like_string = array("A'%", "B%");

$sql = "SELECT p.last_name, p.first_name
FROM person p
WHERE p.last_name LIKE ? AND p.first_name LIKE ? ";

$fields = array($like_string[0], $like_string[1]);
$stmt = $this->pdb->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($fields);
$result = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

However this code, where the string array is built within the php code, does not, and I do not understand why.

```
// e.g $search val = "A', B";
$search_array = explode(',',$search_val);
$like_string[0] = trim($search_array[0]) . "%";
$like_string[1] = trim($search_array[1]) . "%";
```

The results from the code above produces array values of:

```
$like_string[0] = "A'%"
$like_string[1] = "B%"
```

yet no rows are returned.  I have even tried adding addslashes as seen below - still no rows fetched:

```
// e.g $search val = "A', B";
$search_array = explode(',',$search_val);
$like_string[0] = addslashes(trim($search_array[0]) . "%");
$like_string[1] = addslashes(trim($search_array[1]) . "%");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As an update to a previous comment, the code below produces

```
$search_val = "A', B";
$search_array = explode(',',$search_val);
$like_string[0] = trim($search_array[0]) . "%";
$like_string[1] = trim($search_array[1]) . "%";
var_dump($like_string);
```

the following output from var_dump

```
array (size=2)
0 => string 'A'%' (length=3)
1 => string 'B%' (length=2)
```

And I believe the issue is that the resultant strings above are not surrounded in double quotes.  So how do I force that to occur?

Comment: Well... `A',` is different from `A'` :-?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue.  The search string entered by the user was being sanitized by calling

```
escape_string(filter_var($item_to_prep, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH));
```

This caused a conflict with the PDO functions.